# Haskell-- Searching List of List for element

Tags: search, haskell

I would like to search a list of a list of Chars,  `[[Char]]` determine whether a Char is within the list, returning true or false.  So far I have this,

```
    scanBoard :: [[Char]] -> Bool
    scanBoard board 
        | 'r' `elem` board = True
        | 'i' `elem` board = True
        | otherwise = False
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of searching, you can convert your list of lists to a single list using `concat`, and then search within the derived list using `elem`, like so:

```
scanBoard :: [[Char]] -> Bool
scanBoard board 
        | elem 'r' $ concat board = True
        | elem 'i' $ concat board = True
        | otherwise = False
```

Alternatively, we can do this recursively as shown below:

```
scanBoard :: [[Char]] -> Bool
scanBoard [[]] = False
scanBoard [x] = (elem 'r' x || elem 'i' x)
scanBoard board@(x:xs) = (elem 'r' x || elem 'i' x) || scanBoard xs
```

This will eliminate the need for the `concat` operation, and allow use to work directly with the list of lists using pattern matching.

Answer (score 6):

we can create a predicate to test on a character:

```
\c -> (c == 'r') || (c == 'i')
```

then we can check that any sublist has any such char

```
scanBoard :: [[Char]] -> Bool
scanBoard = any $ any pred where
    pred = \c -> (c == 'r') || (c == 'i')
```